# faster subsetting of data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a datatable "d" and I am currently subsetting like this:

```
   d[d$time >= as.POSIXct("2016-01-01 00:31:13",tz="GMT") & d$category =="b" & num1==8 & num2>=4 & num3 ==7, ]
```

What is the fastest way to subset the rows of a data table? Can this be made faster?

Thank you.

Here is the code:

```
 times= as.POSIXct("2016-01-01",tz="GMT")+seq(1,2000,by = 1)
d =data.table(time= times,  category1 = rep(c("a","b"),1000), num1=rep(c(2,8),1000), num2=rep(c(3,4),1000), num3=rep(c(5,7),1000))
setkey(d,time)#    
d[d$time >= as.POSIXct("2016-01-01 00:31:13",tz="GMT") & d$category =="b" & num1==8 & num2>=4 & num3 ==7, ]
```

Comment: I got rid of the $ and it was still the same time

Comment: Why are you subsetting it? Just to have a look at the result?

Comment: @David what do you mean " you don't need all these calls".  I need to subset on those columns.Let's forget about $ because that doesn't improve performance. I use system.time to test speed.

Comment: system.time on your example is instant. Do you have a better example or are you doing this repeatedly for some reason? If you are doing it varying the values that you are `==` testing, maybe you should familiarize yourself with the core syntax of data.tables, which involves grouping by values.

Comment: this is a toy example so it is instant. when you have 40 columns and 200k rows there is a differnece. I am repeatedly subsetting. Can you provide an example of grouping. In my example I left out the fact that time is the key

Comment: Ok, I have no idea why one would repeatedly subset using the exact same query (same values being equality tested, same date being inequality tested), so I guess the true performance problem will remain a mystery to me.

Comment: Frank lets say you you have 2 data tables and need to check if a row in data table 1 is in data table 2. If it is in  table2 you need to mark off the row that matched in data table 2 so you do not match on that again.  Then you append some values from datatable1 one to datatable2.  Then you keep going to the next row in data table 1

Comment: Ok. That sounds like a common case, but the standard way of handling it would be with a merge, like `DT2[DT1, which=TRUE]` will tell you which rows of DT1 found matches in DT2. As far as appending or dynamically growing objects, that is usually not a good idea in R and can be avoided

Comment: But a "match" in that case might include the same row in DT2 TWICE. I need to keep track of the matches as they occur and make sure those rows in DT2 are not matched again

Comment: Either way, sounds best suited to a merge. `DT2[DT1]` will allow you to see what the matches look like, and if you are concerned about doing things per row of DT1, the idiom would be `DT2[DT1, do_things, by=.EACHI]`

Comment: @Frank can you look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36209734/repeated-subsetting-can-you-make-this-process-faster

Comment: if one of the question covers another one, consider closing one of them, so users will know which one to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the general approach you've laid out is what you want to do, you can get a speed improvement by chaining the `&` conditions rather than having them all in a single call to `[.data.table`. The more `&` conditions, the more improvement you get.

```
library(data.table)

# Create a big table to play with
set.seed(1987)
n <- 1e7
myDT <- data.table(X = sample(LETTERS, n, replace = TRUE),
                   Y = sample(1:1000, n, replace = TRUE),
                   Z = sample(1:1000, n, replace = TRUE))
myDT # 10 million rows

system.time(myDT[X %in% c("R", "S", "G") & Y <= 30 & Z >= 500]) #0.86s
system.time(myDT[X %in% c("R", "S", "G")][Y <= 30][Z >= 500]) #0.19s
```

Note: logically this won't work with or `|` conditions.